# AngularJS - Dynamically change class and load JSON - two things, really

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm facing an issue (or probably two) that is frustrating the swearwords out of me; keep in mind, I'm a fairly beginner coder, so there's a good chance I'm missing something obvious.

One: I've got a page that has a sidebar that is hidden via a class containing margin-left: -90%.  When the class is removed, the bar slides in to fill the whole screen.  I can handle this really easily with jQuery, but I'd rather stick as much as possible in Angular - to this end, I've given it the following code:

```
<div id="detail_box" ng-class="{d_hide: dVis}">
    <a href="" class="box_close" ng-click="hide()"></a>
    <div tw-detail></div> 
</div>
```

Which, as you can see, has a class that refers to a variable in a controller, and a link that has an ng-click connected to a function.  The controller in question is stupidly simple, and relies on $rootScope variables.  I'm only using rootScope because in total, over my whole page, I have two variables that will need to change dynamically, but be the same, for every controller and directive I've made.  The connecting scope and controller are here:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.currentUrl = 'visual/design/1/';
    $rootScope.detail_hide = true;
});

app.controller('navController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 
    function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.dVis = $rootScope.detail_hide;

    $scope.hide = function(){ 
        $rootScope.detail_hide = false;
    }
}]);
```

Now, I've used console.log from my ng-click to see that it is picking up clicks, and I've used console.log to make sure that the detail_hide part of rootScope is changing.  If I change true to false by hand in my app.js, the detail page hides itself just fine... but that ng-click doesn't actually *do* what I'm trying when I test it on the page.  It's *painful* and I can't understand why changing the variable via a function (which I know changes the actual variable in rootScope, thanks to extensive testing) isn't telling my detail box to just go away.

Secondly, and it's connected to the first; dynamically changing the currentUrl in rootScope similarly doesn't change the actual AJAX content I've got stuck inside my twDetail directive, even though, again, the ng-click functions I've written *do* change the variable.  Changing it manually works fine (although images in the second URL aren't loading but that's probably an entirely different problem) but just... what the heck am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is only being run once, when the controller is being setup

```
$scope.dVis = $rootScope.detail_hide
```

Make sure you change the `$scope.dVis` in the `hide` function, like this

```
$scope.hide = function(){ 
    $rootScope.detail_hide = false;
    $scope.dVis = $rootScope.detail_hide;
}
```

I need more info on the twDetail directive to be able to solve that problem

Comment: The twDetail is super simple:  it's this:     app.directive('twDetail', function() {
     return {
      restrict: "A",
      templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){}
     };
    });

with an HTML template that grabs things from two separate JSON files.  But thank you for pointing out that the code needed to be run twice!

Comment: I think the currentUrl is not available in the isolated scope within the directive, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/FHVD9/ for an example on how to pass the url to the directive, and read up on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive